# Associate Multiple records to subgrid using plugin in Dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm associating record to some other entity using AssociateRequest.My question is how to Associate multiple records to subgrid.could you plz anyone clarify me.

```
Entity en=(Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                AssociateRequest assreq = new AssociateRequest();
                assreq.Target = new EntityReference(en.LogicalName,en.Id);
                assreq.RelatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();
                assreq.RelatedEntities.Add(new EntityReference("contact", new Guid("72C8B80B-FEF1-E311-9345-D89D67642EB0")));
                assreq.Relationship = new Relationship("contact_customer_accounts");
                AssociateResponse assresponse = (AssociateResponse)service.Execute(assreq);
```

Comment: can you clarify , associate multiple records to subgrid means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AssociateRequest can only be used to create a relationship between two records. If you need to associate a record multiple times, you will have to repeat the procedure for every single relationship.

You can pack the AssociateRequest's into an ExecuteMultipleRequest and save some roundtrips to the server. Please, keep in mind: the requests that are in the ExecuteMultipleRequest do not participate in the same database transaction.

Comment: Thanks for Suggesting

Answer (score 0):

```
OrganizationRequestCollection associateRequestCollection = new OrganizationRequestCollection();
            Entity en = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
```

> you will have to create AssociateRequest for every single
>   relationship and add them int associateRequestCollection object like below

```
AssociateRequest assreq = new AssociateRequest();
        assreq.Target = new EntityReference(en.LogicalName, en.Id);
        assreq.RelatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();
        assreq.RelatedEntities.Add(new EntityReference("contact", new Guid("72C8B80B-FEF1-E311-9345-D89D67642EB0")));
        assreq.Relationship = new Relationship("contact_customer_accounts");
        associateRequestCollection.Add(assreq);
```

> //Process the Create Multiple emails against Contact Ids;

```
ExecuteMultipleResponse emResponses = ExecuteCRMMultipleRequest(associateRequestCollection);
private ExecuteMultipleResponse ExecuteCrmMultipleRequest(OrganizationRequestCollection associateRequestCollection)
        {
            ExecuteMultipleRequest emRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest
            {
                Requests = associateRequestCollection,
                Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings
                {
                    ContinueOnError = true,
                    ReturnResponses = true
                }
            };

            return (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(emRequest);
        }
```